# Can not ssh in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I have:

PC A (Ubuntu 14.04)

PC B (Ubuntu 16.04)

Server S1 (CentOS)

Server S2 (Unknown)

Stage:

ssh my_user@S1 from computer A  -----> OK

ssh my_user@S1 from computer B  -----> OK

ssh my_user@S2 from computer A  -----> OK

ssh my_user@S2 from computer B  -----> failed

This is error detail:

```
ssh myuser@S2_address -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to S2_address [S2_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/vinhphat/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

This problem occurs when I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does Server S2 require key-based authentication? if so does Computer B possess the appropriate private key file, and are its permissions correct?

Comment: There is no need for key authentication when I use computer A and computer B (which before upgrade to new ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I had this and it was because my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file was blank.

I reinstalled the ssh packages and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh*
sudo apt get install openssh-server
```